# jQuery toggle not toggling two divs

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm working on a navigation element where you click on a button and a menu bar slides open revealing the links to other pages. It currently hides the `.links` divs on load but won't toggle the `.links` divs and `#menuTitle` div. I also tried to manually change the css display properties but couldn't get that working either. Here's my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".links").hide()

  $("#hamburger").on("click", function() {
    $("i").toggle(function() {
      // Changes width of menu bar
      var menuWidth = $("#menu").width() == 700 ? "100px" : "700px";
      $("#menu").animate({
        width: menuWidth
      });

      $('#menuTitle, .links').toggle();
    })
  })
})
```

```css
#menu {
  background-color: #000;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  color: #fff;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#hamburger {
  background-color: #000;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="d-flex me-5">
  <div class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center me-3" id="menu">
    <div class="fs-3" id="menuTitle">Menu</div>
    <div class="links">
      <a class="nav-link links active" href="#">Home</a>
      <a class="nav-link links" href="#">Description</a>
      <a class="nav-link links" href="#">Work Experience</a>
      <a class="nav-link links" href="#">Projects</a>
      <a class="nav-link links" href="#">Education</a>
      <a class="nav-link links" href="#">Certifications</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center" id="hamburger">
    <a href="#" class="btn">
      <i class="fas fa-bars fa-2x" id="bars"></i>
      <i class="fas fa-times fa-2x" id="times"></i>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I suspect the problem is having `<a class="links">` inside `<div class="links">`

Comment: took the links out of the a tags and still doesn't work

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do with `$("i").toggle()`. That's an obsolete event handling method that has been deprecated.

Comment: You shouldn't add event handlers inside other event handlers. Every time you click on the hamburger it adds another toggle handler to `i`.

Comment: @Barmar what should i use instead of toggle? didn't realize i shouldn't nest event handlers. still new to this. i moved the dual toggle out of the i one and it works now. Thanks. what's the correct way instead of toggle? hide and show or something else?

Comment: You should use `$("i").click()`, and put it outside `$("#hamburger").click()`.

Comment: ok. thanks for the help